# How do I want to manage different user files on Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Lets say I am building a file upload service and only want User1 to see User1 files on request and User2 to see User2 files, etc.

I'm able to upload files fine, but I want to only allow the logged in user to have access to his/her files. Do I create a custom IAM user on AWS at the same time I create one on my website or do I use presigned urls?

Not quite sure how this works.

Answer (score 3):

I would not give users direct access to the AWS S3 API, so I would not create an IAM user account for each of your users. I would recommend keeping each user's files stored under a prefix by their user ID just for the sake of making it easy to clean up old users, determine how much space each user is using, etc.

For providing users access to their files I would definitely recommend generating presigned URLs in your application whenever the user needs to upload or download a file.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you manage permissions in your application – so you have your own database with information about which S3 file belongs to which user, metadata etc.

The only IAM user you need is then your application. You don’t give your AWS/IAM access keys to anyone.

When user wants to download the file you give them the presigned S3 URL. Or the S3 files can be public-read and you just give them the URL if that’s ok for your use case.

Comment: So when they login, I generate a presigned URL for each of the files they've uploaded one by one, so they are able to retrieve them?

Comment: @JohnLippson No, you generate presigned URL only for the file they want to download – when it’s needed.

Comment: So you give them URL not to S3, but to your app, and when they click it, your app generates presigned url and redirects them to this url.

Comment: Actually, it is very easy to generate a Pre-Signed URL. When your web application generates a web page, the links on the page can be pre-signed URLs. So, when they click them, they directly access the object from Amazon S3. However, the links expire after a period of time (eg 15 minutes) so they need to go back into the app to get new links after that.